# storing data from excel sheet to db in ror

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, roo-gem

Suppose I have a excel sheet that contains data to be stored in the db.I used roo gem and inserted the data from excel sheet successfully.Now I am trying to validate.
Assume my excel sheet as:

```
s.no  name    age
 1    abc     12
 2    def     qwer
 3    asd     23
```

when I upload this sheet, the 2 row data is roll-backed and 1,3 row data is stored in db.
What I am trying to do is if rollback operation occurs then the remaining records should not be stored in db.i.e the row 3 data should not be stored as row 2 is roll-backed.Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

An update:
Here is my code in controller:

```
def  fetch_excel_data

ex = Roo::Excel.new("/desktop/abc.xls")
ex.default_sheet = ex.sheets[0]
2.upto(ex.last_row) do |line| 
    name = ex.cell(line,2)
    age = ex.cell(line,ex.last_column)
    byebug
    @product = Product.create(:name => name,:age => age)
     @product.save!
     flash[:success] = "data is stored successfully"
end
end
```

I want to roll-back entire excel sheet not only records..Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to parse and insert the sheet?

Comment: You can break the loop if any record is not  valid that will not save further records

Answer (score 1):

You can break the loop if any record is not valid that will not save further records

Something like

```
CSV.foreach("file.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  user = User.new(name: row['name'], age: row['age'])
  break unless user.valid?
  user.save
end
```

**EDIT:**

Taking help from @Rais suggestion you can do somthing like this

```
User.transaction do
  CSV.foreach("file.csv", headers: true) do |row|
    User.create!(name: row['name'], age: row['age'])
  end
end
```

Comment: This is working in the case where i want to rollback next records.But i want to rollback entire sheet.Is there any solution for that?@Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Just to add,you can achieve atomicity using [ActiveRecord Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

**Quoting from rails api documentation-**

> Transactions are protective blocks where SQL statements are only
>   permanent if they can all succeed as one atomic action. The classic
>   example is a transfer between two accounts where you can only have a
>   deposit if the withdrawal succeeded and vice versa. Transactions
>   enforce the integrity of the database and guard the data against
>   program errors or database break-downs. So basically you should use
>   transaction blocks whenever you have a number of statements that must
>   be executed together or not at all.

For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
end
```

> This example will only take money from David and give it to Mary if
>   neither withdrawal nor deposit raise an exception. Exceptions will
>   force a ROLLBACK that returns the database to the state before the
>   transaction began. Be aware, though, that the objects will not have
>   their instance data returned to their pre-transactional state.

Comment: Ahh you have to do `create!`